# Spring Cache Error Handler - Send a Response back on CacheEvict Error

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-cache

I am working on a fallback procedure for when the connection fail (or another error) occurs. I've created the CacheConfiguration/CacheErrorHandler to handle the errors and log them. The application successfully switches between using the cache and going through the normal process when Redis fails.

However, the way I've implemented cache eviction endpoint (via the `@cacheEvict` annotation), it is essentially an empty method.

```
@DeleteMapping(value = "/cache/clear")
@CacheEvict(value = {_values_}, allEntries = true)     
public ResponseEntity<String> clearAllCache() {return ResponseEntity.ok("OK"); }
```

Current CacheErrorHandler

```
@Override
public CacheErrorHandler errorHandler() {
    return new CacheErrorHandler() {
        @Override
    public void handleCacheEvictError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key) {
        LOGGER.warn("Failure evicting from cache: " + cache.getName() + ", exception: " + exception);
        }
}
```

Logger will output the cacheEvictError but the response will send back "OK" to the client.
Is there a way to catch the cache error and send a different response saying that the cache evict failed?

I've tried adding a try-catch to throw an exception inside the endpoint but that went nowhere. Couldn't seem to find any examples online to solve this specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to keep in mind here is that Spring's `@CacheEvict` annotation and behavior is called "**after**" the method (by default) on which the annotation is declared, which in your case is the `clearAllCache()` Web service method.

Although, you can configure the cache eviction to occur before the (actual) `clearAllCache()` Web service method is called, like so:

```java
@CacheEvict(cacheNames = { ... }, allEntries = true, beforeInvocation = true)
public ResponseEntity<String> clearAllCache() {
  // ...
}
```

That is, using the `beforeInvocation` attribute on the `@CacheEvict` annotation, set to `true`, the cache eviction (for all entries) will occur before the actual `clearAllCache()` method is invoked.

> NOTE: Logically, if the invocation happens after the `clearAllCache()` method has already been called, then you really have no way to respond if the cache eviction (or rather, the "`clear`" operation) was unsuccessful.  So you must configure the cache eviction to occur before your Web service method gets invoked, first of all.

Next, you need someway to know that your custom `CacheErrorHandler` was invoked on an error occurring in your caching provider (e.g. Redis) during eviction (or technically, the `Cache.clear()` operation in this case, since you evicting "all entries").

Another thing to keep in mind here is that since you appear to be operating in Web environment (e.g. a Servlet container like Tomcat or Jetty, or other) then you need to keep "Thread Safety" in mind since each HTTP request and corresponding Web handler method, like the `clearAllCache()` method called on HTTP DELETE, will be invoked from a separate Thread (i.e. Thread per (HTTP) Request model).

So, you can solve that problem using a Java `ThreadLocal` declared inside your custom `CacheErrorHandler` class to capture the necessary state / information that is needed once the `clearAllCache()` method is called.

I have wrote one such [example test class](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/RespondingToFailedCacheEvictionIntegrationTests.java) demonstrating how you could accomplish this.  The key to this implementation (solution) is the [proper configuration of the cache eviction](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/RespondingToFailedCacheEvictionIntegrationTests.java#L137) and the [use of the `ThreadLocal`](https://github.com/jxblum/stackoverflow-questions-answers/blob/master/spring-cache/src/test/java/io/stackoverflow/questions/spring/cache/RespondingToFailedCacheEvictionIntegrationTests.java#L150) in the custom `CacheErrorHandler`.

My test is not specifically configured as a Web-based service (e.g. using Spring Web MVC, or anything like that), but I modeled the test use case after your particular situation.  I also made use of Mockito to spy on the Spring caching infrastructure to always throw a RuntimeException anytime a `Cache` eviction based operation occurs (e.g. `evict(key)` or `clear()`, etc).

Of course, there are probably better, more robust ways to implement this solution, but this at least demonstrates that it is possible.

Hopefully, this gives you more ideas.